Can't Install App From Google Play - Ionic
I'm having trouble with my ionic 5 app. A while ago I had to update the target sdk version of my app to version 33 (this was mandatory from Google). These are my preferences in my config.xml:
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" /> <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
Ever since I made that change nor me or my users are able to install the app from Google Play. I can search and see the app, download it, but doesn't install. I get the following error message: "Can't install [APP-NAME] Try again, and if it still doesn't work see common ways to fix the problem".
I've tried these common ways but it still doesn't seem to fix the problem and seems to be a widespread problem, not just in my device.

Is it a mismatch between release and debug builds? E.g. do you have a debug build on your device, and are trying to replace it with a release build from the play store? That has caused these kinds of errors for me in the past. What happens if you uninstall the app from your device first, before installing it from the store?

Hey there, I don't have the app installed on the device when trying to install from Google. Play.

Hmmm, sorry, can't help then. I've only ever seen that error when the app's already been installed on the device.
